# rewriteRule for URL path not working correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with a URL problem I've encountered with a rewriteRule.

What I need it to do is following: example.com/en/page/page/

At the moment the following works fine: example.com/en/page/

But once it goes like "example.com/en/page/page/" I receive a 404 - page not found error even if the page in fact is located in the serverfiles.

The clue here is that I use a variable in the /en/ part of the URL (multilanguage system) and it seems that I cannot figure out how to get it to work with that included.

At the moment I have the following rewriteRule in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&uri=$2 [L]
```

Do any of you have a clue on what might work?

Best regards,
PureDarkness

Comment: Q: `/en/page/` should be served as `index.php?lang=en&uri=page`. How `/en/page/page/` supposed to be served? As I understand it should be `index.php?lang=en&uri=page/page` ??

Comment: The PHP script included in the index file makes it to get the index file based on what folder the url links to, but it should be able to list the index either way if the url is presented like `/en/page/` or `/en/page/page/` each folder containing a different index file. Before I included the `/en/` in the url the following served what I needed: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include anything behind the second `/`. You could try:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&uri=$2 [L]
```

And you can add `[QSA]` if you also need to get the parameters.